# How to fill SVG path with color upto a specific distance?

Tags: svg, curve, ellipse, stroke

I have created an SVG as shown in the below image.

[SVG Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyX7K.png)

Here, I require to give color to the path only to a certain point. It is to represent the progress of a user in his journey.

1. I searched for any SVG properties that could achieve this functionality like `stroke-dashoffset`, and `stroke-dasharray`. But, they didn't work.
2. I tried with stroke animations, but it didn't work.

Next, I thought of achieving this by drawing another path to the required point on the existing path and give `stroke` to that. This would solve my problem.

But, the problem I am facing is that if the required point is on the curved portion of the path shown in the image, I cannot draw the new path exactly overlapping the previous path.

I have drawn the previous curve using this

`d="M 0 130L 820 130M 820 130C 1140 130 1140 466 820 466"`

To draw the new path, I was able to draw only up to `M 0 130L 820 130M 820 130C x1 y1 x2 y2 1049 350`

I could not draw the curve exactly because I don't know how to get the control points x1, y1, x2, and y2. I am thinking of using ellipse equation, tangents and other mathematical stuff, but I don't know how feasible it would be in this case.

Is there any straight approach for giving stroke to the first path up to the required point?

If not, how can I get the control points?

Comment: You should be doing this with animating stroke dasharray & offset - why did this not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `stroke-dasharray`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
<defs>
<style>
path{
  stroke-width: 10;
}
</style>
</defs>
<path d="M 10 10 l 100 0 c 10 10 10 10 0 50 l -100 0" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
<path d="M 10 10 l 100 0 c 10 10 10 10 0 50 l -100 0" stroke="red" fill="transparent" pathLength="1" stroke-dasharray="0.6 0.4"/>
</svg>
```

You can manipulate `stroke-dasharray="0.6 0.4"`. As long as the sum of the values is equal to `pathLength`, you can represent a relative length in the path.

Comment: Hey @vqf, thanks for the answer. But, it seems the stroke is not accurate. If we change the percentages in the `stroke-dasharray` (say 50% 50% or 90% 10%), it is not exactly filling the percentage we specified. And if we add an M value before the C value, it not behaving as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried using the code specified in this `codesandbox link`

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fog-d77d0?file=/index.html

Will you please have a look at it and let me know what went wrong?

Comment: My bad, I had misinterpreted the meaning of `percentage`. You can do it by specifying `pathLength`. I have edited the snippet. Your codesandbox can be adapted to this solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-borg-zbdti You had an unnecessary M op that made it a discontinuous path (it seems to mess up calculation paths). It woks if you remove it.

Comment: Hey @vqf, thanks for the help. I could get the output with what you have said. But, I need to achieve [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pJcX8LvnD0u4NTchFB09s0bmPdgVp0ui/view?usp=sharing) layout.

The number of curves and lines may increase or decrease based on the number of levels.

As you said, if I remove the M before C, I was not able to get the exact shape, and also the method you suggested didn't work out (as per my try out).

Comment: This solution should work fine for any path,. No matter how long, or how many curves it has.  If the fractions are confusing you, you can use actual percentage values by using `pathLength="100"` and `stroke-dasharray="60 40"`.